# Generate styles from specific container in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By default, MUI generates styles like this:

```
.css-15xpdk1 {
  display: flex;
  ...
}
```

I want to make it generate styles from specific root container:

```
#some-root-container .css-15xpdk1 {
  display: flex;
  ...
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out how to do that.
It can be done via **@emotion/cache**

```
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';

const cache = createCache({
  key: 'css-prefix',
  stylisPlugins: [
    (element) => {
      if (element.type === 'rule' && Array.isArray(element.props)) {
        element.props = element.props.map((prop) => (
          prop.startsWith('.') ? `#some-root-container ${prop}` : prop
        ))
      }
    },
  ],
});

function App() {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      ...
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

So now I have styles like this:

```
#some-root-container .css-prefix-9gz3s5{
  ...
}
```

This is exactly what I need